# How to convert script path into JSON?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this website : https://www.epicery.com/c/promos?gclid=CjwKCAjw97P5BRBQEiwAGflV6bGzNEAz7MTIrgelBkTR277v3lhStP5tH0wgxuLj1ytlcQAAjb-cxBoCsVwQAvD_BwE
And I am trying to retrive some info in the script path like the description.
I get the script content with the xpath and make some regex and try to load it as json:

```
script_path = response.xpath('/html/body/script[1]').get()
j_list = re.findall(r'\[(.*)\}\]',script_path)
j = j[0].replace("'","")
json_script = json.loads(j)
```

But I have this following error that I cannot handle :

```
 raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 152446 (char 152445)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrap?

Comment: @Vin I am trying to get some contents in the scipt tag like description or gps_lat long

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want but this works for me:

```
def parse(self, response):
    taxons_str = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "var taxons")]/text()').re_first(r'(?s)var taxons = (.+?)var shops')
    if taxons_str:
        taxons = json.loads(taxons_str)
        for product in taxons:
            process_your_product(product)
```